# Help verifying and simplifying $ \int_0^\infty \cos x^2 dx $ (the Fresnel integral) via complex contour integration

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, proof-writing, contour-integration

Find $ \int_0^\infty \cos x^2 dx $.

*Note: This is the Fresnel integral, whose derivation is available on this site and [elsewhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral).  I'd like verification of* my *proof, as well any recommended improvements to the exposition, which to me is simpler than much of what's published.*

**Solution**:

We use the technique of contour integrals in the complex plane, creating three contours: $\alpha$, from $0$ to $R$ along the real axis; $\beta$, from $R$ to $Re^{i \pi/4}$ in a circular arc, and $\gamma$, from $Re^{i \pi/4}$ to $0$ in a straight line.

We first show that $\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_\beta e^{-z^2}dz = 0$.  $\int_\beta e^{-z^2}dz = \int_0^{\pi/4}e^{-R^2e^{2i\theta}}\cdot iRe^{i\theta}d\theta$.  Since $|e^z| = |e^{\Re(z)}|$ and $|\int f(x) dx| \leq \int |f(x)| dx$, we have $|\int_\beta e^{-z^2}dz| \leq \int_0^{\pi/4} |Re^{-R^2\cos {2\theta}}|d\theta$.  Since $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/4$, $0 \leq \cos {2\theta} \leq 1$, and so this goes to $0$ as $R \to \infty$.  From this, we conclude $\int_\gamma e^{-z^2}dz = - \int_\alpha e^{-z^2}dz$, since $e^{-z^2}$ is entire.

Since the Gaussian integral $\int^\infty_{-\infty} e^{-x^2}dx = \sqrt \pi$, and $e^{-x^2}$ is even, $\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_\gamma e^{-z^2}dz = - \int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx = - \sqrt \pi / 2$.

Also note that $\int_\gamma e^{-z^2} dz = \int_R^0 e^{-[re^{i\pi/4}]^2}e^{i\pi/4}dr = \frac{-\sqrt 2}{2}(1+i)\int_0^Re^{-ir^2}dr$.  Thus, $\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_0^Re^{-ir^2}dr = \sqrt{2\pi}/4 + ki$ for some real $k$, and its complex conjugate $\int_0^Re^{ir^2}dr = \sqrt{2\pi}/4 - ki$.

Finally, we conclude $\int_0^\infty \cos x^2 dx = \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{ix^2} + e^{-ix^2}}{2} dx = \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{4}$, QED.

1. Is my proof correct?
2. I tried to skip mechanical steps while not omitting any conceptual leaps.  My goal is for the exposition to be simple, clear, and direct.  Did I succeed?
3. Could the writing and exposition be improved? How?

Comment: I'm concerned about the $\cos 2 \theta$ part.  Did I just wave my hands? My argument is that, except at the endpoint, which can be ignored for an integral, $\cos 2 \theta > 0$, and so $R e ^ {-R^2 \cos 2 \theta}$ will vanish for sufficiently large $R$.  How do I state this rigorously yet clearly?

Comment: @SRobertJames I posted a solution that addresses this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is true that $\lim_{R\to \infty}Re^{-R^2\cos(2\theta)}=0$ for $\theta\in [0,\pi/4)$, it is ***not*** true for $\theta =\pi/4$.  Moreover, we need to justify interchanging the order of the limit and the integral.

One way to proceed, is to exploit the fact that for  $\theta \in [0,\pi/2]$, $ \sin(\theta)\ge 2\theta/\pi$.  Then, we have the following estimates

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/4}Re^{-R^2\cos(2\theta)}\,d\theta&=\frac R2\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{-R^2\sin(\theta)}\,d\theta\\\\
&\le \frac R2\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{-R^2 (2\theta/\pi)}\,d\theta\\\\
&=\frac \pi4 \left(\frac{1-e^{-R^2}}{R}\right)
\end{align}$$

from which we find the limit as $R\to \infty$ is indeed equal to $0$.

As for the rest of the proof, it seems fine.  But, since you found that

$$e^{i\pi/4}\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_0^R e^{-it^2}\,dt=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}$$

one you could instantly conclude that

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-it^2}\,dt=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}e^{-i\pi/4}$$

Now, simply take the real part of both sides to arrive at the coveted result.

Comment: Thanks! "you could instantly conclude..." I don't see which parts of my proof this could allow me to omit.  Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I wasn't aware that $\sin \theta \geq 2 \theta / \pi$.  I see it's known as Jordan's inequality, with a geometric proof ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_inequality ).  Given that I wasn't aware of such, is there a way I could add rigor to my intuition that, for any $\theta$ (except at the end point $\pi/4$, which can be ignored, $R$ will eventually overwhelm it? Would a full-fledged $\epsilon - \delta$ argument be in order?

Comment: @SRobertJames You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: @SRobertJames As far as elaborating, other than the first part, your proof is fine.  However, you had the factor $e^{i\pi/4}$ and wrote it in Cartesian coordinates.  This was unnecessary and seems to make things just a bit less efficient.  Just compare the number of steps in your proof and my post herein.  ;-)

Comment: @SRobertJames One can prove that $f(x)=\sin(x)-(2/\pi)x\ge 0$ for $x\in [0,\pi/2]$ without appealing to geometry.  Just note that $f(0)=f(\pi/2)=0$, $f'(0)=1-2/\pi>0$, and $f''(x)=-\sin(x)\le 0$.  

Another way forward is to use the estimate

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}Re^{-R^2\sin(x)}\,dx\le \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac R{1+R^2\sin(x)}\,dx$$

You can evaluate the right-hand side in closed form and show that it is $O(1/R)$.

Comment: Doesn't the switch from $\cos$ to $\sin$ require negating the integral? It resolves to zero either way, of course, but it seems that without this, the first equation is incorrect.

Comment: @SRobertJames To what are you referring?

Comment: The first equation in your answer has cos in the integrand on the left and sin on the right.  I accept this as correct, since it's done over $(0, \pi/2)$, and the variable of integration appears nowhere else, but only if you negate the integral.

Comment: @SRobertJames First, enforce the substitution $\theta\mapsto \theta/2$.  The follow this with a second substitution $\theta\mapsto \pi/2-\theta$.  Then, we have $$\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/4}Re^{-R^2\cos(2\theta)}\,d\theta&\overbrace{=}^{\theta\mapsto \theta/2}\frac R2 \int_0^{\pi/2} e^{-R^2\cos(\theta)}\,d\theta\\\\
&\overbrace{=}^{\theta\mapsto \pi/2-\theta}\frac R2\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{-R^2\sin(\theta)}\,d\theta\\\\
\end{align}$$Does that help to clarify?

Comment: Got it, thanks.  $\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos \theta d\theta = \int_{\pi/2}^0\cos(\pi/2 - \theta)(-1)d\theta = \int_0^{\pi/2}\sin\theta d\theta$.  Indeed, this seems like remedial calculus, but perhaps my integration by substitution needs sharpening! Also, worth noting that the graph of sin and cos makes this obvious.

Comment: @SRobertJames Pleased to hear that you have it now!